# Android: Ter um job para verificar url

Tags: android

Necessito ter um job para uma app minha que se execute todos os dias para verificar se uma URL está a devolver dados corretos. Caso não devolva, deve chegar-me um e-mail a avisar.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como se faz isto?

Sei que posso verificar se a URL funciona por JUnit, mas o meu problema é programar esta execução todos os dias em Android.

Comment: Eu recomendo fortemente a dar uma olhada na API do Job Scheduler ou semelhantes.

Answer (score 0):

Para agendar tarefas que serão executadas repetidas vezes no futuro, você pode utilizar o [mecanismo de *Alarms*](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) do Android.

Dependendo do seu caso de uso os parâmetros e o [tipo de alarme](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#type) podem mudar, mas é algo do tipo:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

// Intent para invocar uma classe no horário agendado
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Cria um calendário e muda sua hora para 14:00
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// setInexactRepeating() requer um dos intervalos definidos nas constantes do AlarmManager
// Neste exemplo o intervalo é AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY (um dia)
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Neste exemplo foi criado um alarme para as 14h do dia atual, com uma repetição diária inexata.